# RecyclerView items stick to each other

Tags: android

I'm making news application, or smth. I have RecyclerView with CardViews. When i launch it, every card stick to other, so it looks like one big card. How can i divide it?

Card:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:id="@+id/markPhoto"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/markPhoto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/x"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/markPhoto" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen looks that way
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding adds space inside an element, and margin adds space outside. I would try adding `android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"` to your CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" >
```

Comment: ty, it helps. Add margin to RelativeLayout didnt solve the problem, but to CardView halped. Thanks a lot

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Add margin to RelativeLayout

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:id="@+id/markPhoto"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
            .
            .
            .
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For your information**

> Yes. You can use padding nice.But it is awesome if you customize your
>   cardView

add

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp" //for corner radius
android:layout_margin="5dp"         //for separating views
```

And you can add border. Try this

Create bg.xml in `drawable` folder and paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#F00" />
    <size android:width="10dp"/>

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0.1dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
</shape>
```

add `android:background="@drawable/bg"` to your card view

Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/).

[image]